# Trying to establish connection to read files in an Access Database, having static error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Need to pull table names from an access database and getting static error

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory factory = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

    System.Data.DataTable usersTables = null;
    using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection connection = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory.CreateConnection()) ;
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = c:\\test\\test.mdb";
        string[] restrictions = new string[4];
        restrictions[3] = "Table";

        connection.Open();
        usersTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);
    }
    List<string> tableNames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i< usersTables.Rows.Count; i++)
        tableNames.Add(usersTables.Rows[i][2].ToString());
}
```

I need a list of tables names from my access server, but get an error with the CreateConnnection() area because its a non-static field. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use a static method of the type instead of the method of the instance you created.

Replace `System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory.CreateConnection()` with `factory.CreateConnection()`:

```
using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection connection = (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection)factory.CreateConnection())
```

You also have a spurious semi-colon after your `using` statement which must be removed.